# How to solve this improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$\int _{ 0 }^{ 4 }{ \frac { 4 }{ x-4 }  } $

**My attempt**

$\lim _{ b\rightarrow 4^- }$$\int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ \frac { 4 }{ x-4 }  } $

My doubt is why did we need to take Limit as $b\rightarrow 4^- $ but not just $b\rightarrow 4 $

Comment: You must take the limit from below because of the singularity.

Comment: Your integral diverges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the bottom bound of your improper integral is *less than* the $x$-coordinate of the singularity and your top bound is the $x$-coordinate of the singularity. Thus, you approach the singularity from the right side. Realize that $\lim_{x\to4} {4\over x-4}$ doesn't exist.

Also - your integral is not finite, it diverges. If we approach the antiderivative at $4$ from the right side, you get $-\infty$.

Comment: The fact that it approaches infinity is not a motivation for a integral to diverge. Maybe you should clarify that point i.e. $\lim _{ b\rightarrow 4^- }
\int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ \frac { 4 }{ x-4 }  }=\lim _{ b\rightarrow 4^- } 4\log (4-x)=-\infty$

Comment: @gimusi My mistake, I meant to say "antiderivative" not integrand. Let me edit.

Comment: Well done! Now it is clear. Bye

Answer (score 1):

Because the integral is between $0$ and $4$. If it was between, say $4$ and $6$, we would take the limit as $b\to4^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition we have that

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 4 }{ \frac { 4 }{ x-4 }  }dx=\lim _{ b\rightarrow 4^- }
\int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ \frac { 4 }{ x-4 }  }dx$$

because we are approching the "problematic" point by the left in the interval of integration [0,b].